# Python nested for loop Vs generator for repeatedly iterating over a list provided by a function

Tags: for-loop, iterator, python

The problem is quite simple, I have a method that returns a list.
I want to iterate over every item in this list, and once finished,
call the method to receive a new list, and repeat.

At the moment, my code looks something like:

```
generator = iter([])
while Condition:
    try:
        item = next(generator)
    except StopIteration:
        generator = iter(list_returining_method())
        item = next(generator)
    ...
```

However, previously, I was using a nested `for` loop.

```
while Condition:
    for item in list_returining_method():
        ...
```

While my previous attempt *looks* nicer in some respects, but my current method has some 'advantages':

- if Condition is set to false, the loop ends without having to `break` out of the for loop.

  - an extension of the above reasons, methods with access to Condition can end the loop *without* going over all other items in the said list, or implementing a special check in the for loop.
- The first approach allows skipping items in the loop, should the need arise.
- There is also one less level of indentation. This is more vanity then anything else, but considering that the actual code was part of a class method, the indent level was already pretty high.

To say the least, im *confused* as to which is more appropriate. They both seem to have unique advantages and disadvantages, so if anyone knows the most correct and pythonic approach, I'd really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you use some iterators

```
items = itertools.chain.from_iterable( iter(list_returning_method, None) )

for item in items:
    # do something with item
    print item

    if not Condition:
       break
```

`iter(callable, sentinel)` returns an iterator which produces the result of callable() until it return sentinel.

`itertools.chain.from_iterable` returns an iterator that flattens the original iterator, it will produce the values in the lists produced by the first iterator.

I think that gives you most of the advantages of your method but with a cleaner style.

Comment: This works really well. Although the first line originally looked quite cryptic, this is a much better solution. The only issue I see with it, is when passing arguments to the callable is necessary. Any suggestions on how to resolve this problem?

Comment: @SingularityCat, two options there. You can use functools.partial which combines a function and arguments to create a new function. Or you can write a generator.

Answer (score 1):

There is room for opinion here, but the brevity of the second approach makes it a clear win as far as I'm concerned.  Especially if the use of the `item` variable is limited to within the loop, I would choose the for / in syntax every time.  There have been some problems, involving buffers and state changes within a loop, where I have chosen not to use for / in.  But that is a small minority.